# Домены 3 уровня

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день. Нужна помощь с реализацией следующего:

Вводим в браузер `test.site.ru`, загружается страница `site.ru/index.php?p=test` 
Вводим в браузер `test2.site.ru`, загружается страница `site.ru/index.php?p=test2`

и т.п., но не редирект на эту старницу, а чтоб в браузере оставался домен третьего уровня `test.site.ru`

Когда-то уже делал так:
Добавил в редактор ДНС `test.site.ru` смотрит в IP сервера где стоит сайт (A запись)

В HTaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=test&$1 [NC]
```

И нормально работало, но сейчас задача реализовать подобное без вмешательство в файл зоны или добавлением одного общего правила(какого я не знаю)... т.к. доменов `test, test2, test3` будет много и добавлять каждый руками нереально просто.

Дайте ссылок где можно найти примеры подобного механизма... сутки гуглю - результата ноль.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, ответили на другом сайта - реализация не возможна

Comment: Интересно почему не реализация невозможно? Ведь как то решают же подобные проекты типа укоз, wix и т.д.?

Comment: вот и мне интересно тоже. на стороне сервера это реализуется default Настройками для входящих запросов...

Answer (score 1):

Одно общее правило добавить можно, пишется оно как `* A IPадрес`

на счет htaccess:

> Динамическое зеркало
>
> Описание:
>
> Предположим что есть чудесные страницы
> на удалённых хостах и мы хотим внести
> их в наше пространство имен(сайт). Для
> FTP серверов мы бы использовали
> программу зеркало которая в
> действительности управляет
> обновлениями копий удалённых данных на
> локальной машине. Для веб-сервера мы
> могли бы использовать программу
> webcopy которая делает похожие вещи по
> HTTP. Однако обе эти технологии имеют
> один главный недостток: локальная
> копия актуальна всегда настолько,
> насколько часто мы запускаем эту
> программу. Было бы намного лучше если
> бы зеркало было не статическим должно
> быть полное соответствие копий, вне
> зависимости от частоты запуска этой
> программы. Вместо этого мы хотим
> динамическое зеркало с автоматическим
> обновлением данных когда это
> необходимо (обновление данных на
> удаленном сервере).
>
> Решение:
>
> Для обеспечения этой функции мы
> отобразим удаленную страницу или даже
> полностью удаленный сайт в наше
> веб-пространство используя Proxy
> Throughput опцию ( флаг [P]):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~quux/
RewriteRule ^hotsheet/(.*)$ http://www.tstimpreso.com/hotsheet/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~quux/
RewriteRule ^usa-news\.html$ http://www.quux-corp.com/news/index.html [P]
```

Возможно поможет.